# Minimum and maximum value in a column for a task in a Unix file

Tags: shell, awk

I have a file which contains a task name in the first column and the time taken to complete the task in the second column as below:

```
Task2, 3421
Task3, 3300
Task1, 1000
Task2, 1100
Task3, 1200
Task3, 1209
Task4, 1299
Task3, 1289
Task1, 1389
Task2, 1211
Task5, 1216
Task2, 1416
Task1, 2100
Task6, 2416
Task5, 2216
Task7, 1116
```

Now I have to find the minimum and maximum time taken for each task and output in the below format

```
task, maxtime, min time
```

For example,

```
Task1, 1000, 2100 (from the data given above)
```

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40780716/6769931) for a quasi-"awk-free" answer. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try with `awk`

```
awk '
    BEGIN{FS=","; OFS=", "}
    !($1 in max) || $2>max[$1]{max[$1]=$2}
    !($1 in min) || $2<min[$1]{min[$1]=$2}
    END{
        for(k in max){print k, min[k], max[k]}
    }' input.txt
```

you get,

```
Task1, 1000, 2100
Task2, 1100, 3421
Task3, 1200, 3300
Task4, 1299, 1299
Task5, 1216, 2216
Task6, 2416, 2416
Task7, 1116, 1116
```

Comment: I put these lines in a script and execute  I get  syntax errors awk: syntax error near line 3
awk: bailing out near line 3

Comment: try again, fixed in post

Comment: same error awk: syntax error near line 3
awk: bailing out near line 3

Comment: it works for me [http://imgur.com/hBywkkVl.png](http://imgur.com/hBywkkVl.png), What version of awk do you use?

Comment: @user3369871 you're using old, broken awk (/bin/awk on Solaris), just don't do that. On Solaris use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk.

Comment: @EdMorton Are those Solaris versions easily available for Linux just for quality control purposes,do you know? I don't want to fire up my old Suns...

Comment: sorry, I don't know, but any time you get that specific error message it's from old, broken awk and /usr/xpg4/bin/awk is just another [almost] POSIX awk. Solaris also has nawk but it's much further from POSIX compliance which is why I don't suggest anyone use it.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is to sort by column1 and then by column2 and take 1st and last value for each task like this

```
awk -F, '{arr[$1]=arr[$1] $2} END {for(key in arr) print key, arr[key]}' <(sort -t 1 -k 1,2 file) | awk '{OFS=", "; print $1, $2, $NF}'
```

Sample run:

```
$ cat file 
Task2, 3421
Task3, 3300
Task1, 1000
Task2, 1100
Task3, 1200
Task3, 1209
Task4, 1299
Task3, 1289
Task1, 1389
Task2, 1211
Task5, 1216
Task2, 1416
Task1, 2100
Task6, 2416
Task5, 2216
Task7, 1116
$ sort -t 1 -k 1,2 file
Task1, 1000
Task1, 1389
Task1, 2100
Task2, 1100
Task2, 1211
Task2, 1416
Task2, 3421
Task3, 1200
Task3, 1209
Task3, 1289
Task3, 3300
Task4, 1299
Task5, 1216
Task5, 2216
Task6, 2416
Task7, 1116
$ awk -F, '{arr[$1]=arr[$1] $2} END {for(key in arr) print key, arr[key]}' <(sort -t 1 -k 1,2 file) | awk '{OFS=", "; print $1, $2, $NF}'
Task1, 1000, 2100
Task2, 1100, 3421
Task3, 1200, 3300
Task4, 1299, 1299
Task5, 1216, 2216
Task6, 2416, 2416
Task7, 1116, 1116
```

Comment: why is there same min and max for task4 ?

Comment: @user3369871 because there is only 1 entry for Task4

Comment: there is only one entry for task 7 also but  max time is missing for  task7 in the output

Comment: @user3369871 fixed it

Comment: @ritesh93:  that works but not sure why you have taken  sort -t 1  ( why 1 as field separator ?)

Comment: @ritesh93 : also can you please explain this part  {arr[$1]=arr[$1] $2} END {for(key in arr) print key, arr[key]}  , how this is working ? I have not worked with array or hash on awk before.

Answer (score 1):

Using `gawk`'s [array of arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Arrays-of-Arrays.html):

```
gawk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=","}
      $2>a[$1]["max"]{a[$1]["max"]=$2}
      $2<a[$1]["min"] || !a[$1]["min"] {a[$1]["min"]=$2}
      END {for (i in a){
             print i, a[i]["min"],a[i]["max"]
             }
      }' file
```

Example [here](http://ideone.com/27FIL4).

Answer (score 1):

here is another alternative

```
$ join -t, <(sort file){,} | sort -k1,1 -k2n -k3nr | rev | uniq -2 | rev
```

Answer (score 1):

Another answer using `sort`, `sed` and `awk`

```
sort -k1,1 -k2n input.txt | sed -r ':a;N;$!ba;:b;s/(Task[0-9]+, )([0-9 ,]+)\n?\1([0-9]+)/\1\2, \3/g;tb;' | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=", ";}{print $1, $2, $NF}'
```

Alternative solution using `sort` and `sed` only

```
sort -k1,1 -k2n input.txt | sed -r ':a;N;$!ba;:b;s/(Task[0-9]+, )([0-9 ,]+)\n?\1([0-9]+)/\1\2, \3/g;tb;' | sed -r -e 's/^([^ ]+)\s([^ ]+)\s.*\s([^ ]+)/\1 \2 \3/' -e 's/^([^ ]+)\s([^ ]+)$/\1 \2, \2/'
```

you get,

```
Task1, 1000, 2100
Task2, 1100, 3421
Task3, 1200, 3300
Task4, 1299, 1299
Task5, 1216, 2216
Task6, 2416, 2416
Task7, 1116, 1116
```

Answer (score 0):

`sort` it on first and second column, then awk it. The good thing in this solution (awk part) is that it doesn't store the data  in memory and dump it out in the end but rather outputs data for previous `$1` once a new one is found. Here:

```
$ sort -t, -k1 foo -k2n | \                     # sort 
awk '!($1 in min)    {min[$1]=$2}               # first of each is always min (and max)
      ($1 in min)    {max[$1]=$2}               # every current one is always max
       $1!=p && NR>1 {print p, min[p], max[p]}  # if $1 differs from previous, print previous
                     {p=$1}                     # p is current for next round
       END           {print p, min[p], max[p]}' # dump buffer
Task1, 1000 2100
Task2, 1100 3421
Task3, 1200 3300
Task4, 1299 1299
Task5, 1216 2216
Task6, 2416 2416
Task7, 1116 1116
```

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly bash, if you have some problems with this, I can substitute the awk command with something else... (for example `colrm` if the times start always in the same column).

```
# Keep a list of already processed task names
already_processed=""

# Use read to read only the first column from the data file
while IFS=',' read -ra task; do
  # If the task has already been processed, skip it and go to the next line
  if echo "$already_processed" | grep $task > /dev/null; then
    continue
  else
    # Select all the task with the same name from the data file, take the 
    #+second column and sort it to find the max and the minimum.
    MIN=`grep $task $1 | awk -F',' '{print $2}' | sort -n | head -1`
    MAX=`grep $task $1 | awk -F',' '{print $2}' | sort -n | tail -1`
    # Add the task to the "already_processed" tasks (to be sure each task will 
    #+appear only once in the output
    already_processed="$already_processed:$task"
    # Print the output in the wanted format.
    echo "${task}, ${MIN}, ${MAX}"
  fi

done < $1
```

Just be sure your data file ends with an empty line.

Example:

```
bash <name_of_script_file> <name_of_data_file> | sort    
Task1, 1000, 2100
Task2, 1100, 3421
Task3, 1200, 3300
Task4, 1299, 1299
Task5, 1216, 2216
Task6, 2416, 2416
Task7, 1116, 1116
```